# Не срабатывает редирект, почему?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

```
$(document).on('click','#rem-bot-link',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/panel/del-link',
        data:{
            linkId: $('.link-button').val()
        },
        success: function(item){

        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
        } 
    })
});
```

---

```
router.post('/del-link',(request,response)=>{
    models.db.m_l.destroy({
        where: {id: request.body.linkId}
    })
        .catch(err=>console.log(err));
    response.redirect('/panel/admin');
});
```

Постом отправляется запрос, запись из базы удаляется, все ок, но редирект почему-то не срабатывает. пытался его запихнуть в then  - то же ничего не сработало. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Редирект наверное срабатывает, только вы делаете ajax-запрос и он не может сам по себе изменить страницу. Редирект нужно делать в обработчике success на клиенте

Answer (score 0):

попробуй вернуть редирект

```
return response.redirect('/panel/admin');
```